# Handling AM and PM in DateTime in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

I have a string like this

```
01/01/2019 8:43:55 AM # dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss ??
```

After reading through the [docs](https://nim-lang.org/docs/times.html#parsing-and-formatting-dates) I concluded that the AM part had no corresponding entry in the formats provided. So that I would have to simply test to see if the string ended in either AM or PM and then adjust the hour part accordingly.

Is there something slicker? I didn't really grasp how to use templates yet, and I notice that the last two methods in the docs mention templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `tt` (also, your parsing string should be different for the year and the hour):

```
import times

var dt = parse("01/01/2019 8:43:55 AM", "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss tt")
echo dt
## 2019-01-01T08:43:55+01:00

dt = parse("01/01/2019 8:43:55 PM", "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss tt")
echo dt
## 2019-01-01T20:43:55+01:00
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think I got a bit confused by what the docs said there.